# How to get all autostart programs on Windows?

Tags: python

Is there a way to get all programs that start with windows with python?

For a project I have I need to know what programs start whenever the current user logs in. Meaning Programs like Steam, Discord, Wallpaper engine, etc.

And I also need a way to deactivate that autostart.

So basically I need to find a way to automatically do what you can do manually in the "Autostart" tab of the Task-Manager. See and activate/deactivate all autostart programs.

Problem is that if search for this, all I find are ideas on how to autostart a python program on login... Not even close to what I want.

Comment: some programs start from a shortcut. You can find these shortcuts if you run `shell:startup` (Win+R), or type it into file explorer path.
For the rest of them, I'm not really sure.

Comment: well, you could use `pyautogui` to automatically literally open task manager and navigate to that tab

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Yeah i know, but sadly that doesn't include all programs. Only a very few of them start this way :/

Comment: @Matiiss Good Idea, but i also need to be able to read the current state of each program in the list, because I need to restore the "before" state after I did what I wanted. So I cannot rely on blindly deactivating everything :/ And even if I read the text from screen with opencv (which is not just way to much work, but also not easy to do) it wouldn't even be system language independent. So its not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but that would be actually quite hard.

First of all, there's a ton of different ways to autostart a program. You can download a marvelous Sysinternals "Autoruns" and see how much of everything is starting for your user and your computer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

If your actual goal is to disable/manage **ALL** possible autoruns - check again the number of tabs in the above utility, and drop this thought, as it's impossible, you are not qualified, it won't work.

If, however, you are interested in Task Manager autostart **only**, you should find out what are actual autostart sources that appear there in Task Manager. One of MS blogs mentions that there're two sources: Startup group and Run key. That's just a guess from me, you need to spend more research here.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210223-00/?p=104896

So, now you need to cover at least two these points. To clear Startup entries, you need to navigate to corresponding locations and check / remove corresponding shortcuts:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

(https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=28)

To clear Run entries, you need to check / remove registry entries:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys)

Now, how to do this - this is a separate question :)

Comment: Thanks for this big, well-written answer. It seems like I have failed to specify what programs I mean. I never planned to disable literally everything, only the nonessential things a user enables auto start on by themself. Like Discord, Steam, Wallpaper Engine and stuff like that.

But yeah, it seems like there is no easy solution for this :/ I will check the resources you gave and if I find a good way to find all programs that are the "visible autostart" programs, meaning they make an icon or a start as a window, I will likely make a python module for it, since it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Well, best luck - but such goal seems quite ambitious to me. You need to understand that how to ensure program autostart - that's up to its developer, and there's no any restriction on that. Usually it's either discussed registry keys or *Start Menu/Startup* folder, but it can very well be a service, or even a scheduled task, or a driver. So eventually, you'll have to cover (almost) all tabs visible in Sysinternals Autoruns, which seems quite difficult to me.

Comment: Then, you've said you want to disable "nonessential things", as well as "programs with window" - which is even more complicated. There's no way you can understand what program is "nonessential" for the user (imagine any script the user runs at startup to configure his environment). And whether a program does or does not display a window - that's also something totally unpredictable unless you run it (for example, Discord is launched by an app "Update" with publisher "GitHub" - and then this initial process starts several other processes, one of which is actual Discord GUI with a window).

Comment: i am aware of the problems. But i don't need to find every single last thing that maybe started with a Service or something like that. I checked and all the typical programs are either stated with a registry key in one of the four folders or with a .ink in one of the two folders. The only thing that doesn't start like this that I could find was the Java updater on my PC, all of the other 23 Programs I could find like this. And that's all I need.

Im already working on a system to read all autostarts of those two types and also rewrite them in case they are deleted. Thanks for the help.